# NServiceBus 4.4.2 how do i set the TimeoutPersisterReceiver timespan in config

Tags: c#, nservicebus

How do I increase the timespan of the `TimeoutPersisterReceiver`? it currently retries for ~1min after arming before firing.  I have looked in the documentation but cannot see a config setting for it.

We have been having some network issues that prevented a service from talking to the database causing the `RepeatedFailuresOverTimeCircuitBreaker` to arm itself.

```
 INFO  NServiceBus.CircuitBreakers.RepeatedFailuresOverTimeCircuitBreaker [(null)] - The circuit breaker for TimeoutStorageConnectivity is now in the armed state
```

The database will eventually come back online but by the time it does the circuit breaker has been fired and the Bus has been disposed.  I need to increase the time span of the `NServiceBus.Timeout.Hosting.Windows.TimeoutPersisterReceiver`.

```
NServiceBus.CircuitBreakers.RepeatedFailuresOverTimeCircuitBreaker [(null)] - The circuit breaker for TimeoutStorageConnectivity will now be triggered
FATAL NServiceBus [(null)] - Repeated failures when fetching timeouts from storage, endpoint will be terminated.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to configure it in a class that implements IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops and use the SecondsToSleepBetweenPolls property of the TimeoutPersisterReceiver.

However, I would add that public access to this configuration option was removed in later versions, and I'm not 100% sure why. There may be dragons. See http://bit.ly/1ToyOHb (GitHub).

Comment: As @JustABitOfCode mentions, NSB 5 and later have this setting internalized but these later versions have a setting to control the timeout manager circuit breaker itself. Please take  a look at this doco for details: http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/errors/critical-exception-for-timeout-outages.

Comment: Ive seen that setting - but it seems thats just for v5, I am stuck on 4 and my client is pushing for a quick config change.

Comment: Yes, this is for v5 and later. With v4 your best shot seems to be what @JustABitOfCode suggests.

Answer (score 2):

## Circuit breaker behavior

After researching the code it seems that you would be able to configure the timeout poll interval via `TimeoutPersisterReceiver.SecondsToSleepBetweenPolls` but that does not really matter.

The embedded circuit breaker configuration cannot be adjusted. If an error occurs it is *armed* and if no successful poll succeeds within 2 minutes the circuit breaker action will be triggered which is calling raising a critical error.

Increasing the poll interval will not help here. If you would make the poll interval more than 2 minutes the circuit breaker will *always* be armed thus trigger the action.

- https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/blob/4.7.12/src/NServiceBus.Core/Timeout/Hosting/Windows/TimeoutPersisterReceiver.cs#L150
- https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/blob/4.7.12/src/NServiceBus.Core/CircuitBreakers/RepeatedFailuresOverTimeCircuitBreaker.cs

There is nothing that you can do unfortunately except building your own version that removes the circuit breaker completely.

This behavior can result in issues when your database server does a fail-over.

## Critical error handling

The only possible solution to tackle this condition is by hooking into the critical error handler. Then you know such issue occurs and can do a application shutdown as I suspect that you are currently self-hosting.

You can also try to create a whole new bus instance and 'swap' the broken one with the fresh one but that is a pretty daunting task and I would recommend to *just exit your application*.

Comment: Your spot on i am self-hosting as a service (TopShelf). The workaround i use is to just hook into the critical error handler and forcibly terminate the process. This way the standard windows service control manager can trap the failure and restart etc.