# How to increase NServiceBus 4.x TimeoutPersisterReceiver circuit breaker

Tags: nservicebus, circuit-breaker

How do I increase the timespan of the TimeoutPersisterReceiver for NServicebus 4.x?

How do we get the TimeoutPersisterReceiver object from container and modify the SecondsToSleepBetweenPolls value? Is there any property for number of polls?

The below link is only for `5.x` & `6.x` not for `4.x`:
http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/errors/critical-exception-for-timeout-outages

EDIT: Hi Marcin,
Thanks. I had looked into the link you provided: [How to configure TimeoutPersisterReceiver.SecondsToSleepBetweenPolls](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/2316).

NServicebus gave a fix on 5.x but not for 4.x. 
@JustABitOfCode mentioned configuring TimeoutPersisterReceiver. But I couldn't find any link on how to get that instance from container and set it. 
Also my question is, **Is there way to control number of polls that circuit breaker makes?**

And as I mentioned, I got struck with 4.x for time being. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nservicebus how do i set the TimeoutPersisterReceiver timespan in config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35443131/nservicebus-how-do-i-set-the-timeoutpersisterreceiver-timespan-in-config)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using the latest minor version of NServiceBus 4.x (which at the time of writing is 4.7.12).

First let me state that the frequency of polling the timeout storage depends on which persistence you use and what are the actual expiry times of deferred messages. There is no single setting in NServiceBus that controls the frequency of number of polls per unit of time.

Now getting back to setting the `TimeoutPersisterReceiver.SecondsToSleepBetweenPolls` property, you can do it in a class that implements `IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops` interface. You can get hold of `TimeoutPersisterReceiver` by using property or constructor injection:

```
public class RunWhenBusStartsAndStops : IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops
{
    public TimeoutPersisterReceiver Receiver { get; set; }

    public void Start()
    {
        Receiver.SecondsToSleepBetweenPolls = 15;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
    }
}
```

The dependency injection container should take care of injecting proper instance of `TimeoutPersisterReceiver`.